# I Need to separate 2 texts from a single line array but it don't separate

Tags: javascript, discord.js

this is the code:

```
 const prefix = "&";
  const args = msg.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
  const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();

      if(cmd === 'dm') {
    if (!client.users.fetch(args.join('').slice(2))) 
    return console.log("User not found:(");
      await (await client.users.fetch(args.join('')))
      .send(args.join(''))
      .catch(() => { console.log("User has DMs closed or has no mutual servers with the bot or blocked the bot :(");})
  
}
```

what i want is: &dm <user_id> 
but in console it see: user_id: Value "1761208364761098oi" is not snowflake.
^^ "oi" is the message that i tested to sent.

im using discord.js v12!

Answer (score 1):

Try this: (update)

```
client.on('message', msg => {
    const prefix = "&";
    const args = msg.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
    const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();
      if (cmd === `rep`){
        let destinataire = msg.guild.member(msg.mentions.users.first());
        
        if (!destinataire){
            return msg.channel.send("User not found");
        }
        client.users.cache.get(destinataire.id).send(args.join(" "));
    }
})
```

Comment: but i can't dm another person, but thanks anyways!

Comment: @Floppinqq do u mind marking it as an answer please :) it makes things easier for future readers and both asker and answerer get reputation points for it!